# Javafx vs java applets

Tags: javafx, applet

Why are java applets outdated and why is JavaFX better?
I've tried asking this question all around but all I received was that "Just because" and this, frankly, shows that no one is willing to find out *WHY.* I want a clear answer on this.
Thank you!

Comment: Applets have been deprecated because of dwindling support which was caused, at least in part, by security concerns.

Comment: Is it useless to learn about applets then?

Comment: Why would you want to waste your time with a technology which is not supported anymore by modern browsers and does not even exist anymore in the latest Java 11?

Comment: @mipa Legacy code is still a thing, sadly. That would be the only practical reason I can think of.

Comment: *"Is it useless to learn about applets then?"* Definitely! The question is as to which GUI frameworks to learn for **desktop** development, e.g. Swing (which, like AWT, also offered applets) or Java-FX or ..

Comment: Can someone help me in a project I'm doing? No, I'm not asking for answers at all. I've done most of the code, but I really need help with some errors I have